# Download zip + file in memory

Tags: c#

I tried searching some topics but not found the solution to the problem. Someone explain to me why my txt is coming empty?

```
  this.Response.Clear();
  this.Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
  this.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Outro.zip");

  System.IO.FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Teste\Teste.txt");
  byte[] bytes = new byte[reader.ReadByte()];  
  using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
  {

      using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
       {

         stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
         zipFile.AddEntry("Arquivo.txt", stream);
         zipFile.Save(this.Response.OutputStream);

       }

       zipFile.Dispose();
   }

 }
```

Comment: Which text file? Is _Teste.txt_ being read as if it's empty? Is _Arquivo.txt_ or some other part being output empty? Is the original _Teste.txt_ **actually empty?**

Comment: You are creating a new MemoryStream and immediately start reading from it. Perhaps you ment to `Write` your bytes to the stream?

Answer (score 3):

[`ReadByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte.aspx) reads a single byte!

Take a look at the example here [`FileStream.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx)

Comment: Not only that, but will it not be implicitly casted to an integer in that array declaration? (Confirmed: implicitly casted)

Comment: I would suggest `File.ReadAllBytes()` instead of `FileStream.Read()`.

Comment: @user1908061 : sure, you could use that provided you are ok with reading entire file into memory...

Comment: @MitchWheat He has to read the whole file into memory, because he wants to generate a zip file out of it. How would you incrementally create a zip using that library?